# How to unify separate digits when iterating string

Tags: python, string, loops, type-conversion, integer

I'm trying to iterate over a string and get all the numbers so that I can add them to a list, which I need for another task. I have multiple functions that recurrsively refer to each other and the original input is a list of data. The problem is that when I print the string I get the right output, but if I iterate over it and print all the indexes I get seperate digits, so 1,1 instead of 11 or 9,3 instead of 93. Does anyone have a simple solution to this problem? I'm not Quite experienced in programming so it may seem like a simple task but I can't figure it out at the moment. Here's my code for the problem part.

```
numbers = names.split('\t')[1].split(' ')[1]
print numbers
```

some of the output:

```
8
44
46
86
```

now if I use the following code:

```
numbers = names.split('\t')[1].split(' ')[1]
for i in numbers:
    print i
```

I get the following output:

```
8
4
4
4
6
8
6
```

or when I convert to a list:

```
numbers = names.split('\t')[1].split(' ')[1]
print list(numbers)
```

output:

```
['8']
['4', '4']
['4', '6']
['8', '6']
```

The input `names` is structured in the following way: `Andy Gray\t  2807 53`
where I have many more names, but they are all structured like this.

I then split by `\t` to remove the names and then split again by `' '` to get the numbers. I then have 2 numbers and take the second index to get the numbers I want, which are the second numbers next to the name.

My only goal for now is to get the 'complete' digits, so the output as it is like when I print it. I need to be able to get a list of those numbers as integers where every index is the complete digit, so `[8,44,46,86]` etc. I can then iterate over the numbers and use them. Once I can do that I know what to do, but I'm stuck at this point for now. Any help would be nice.

Link to complete input and python code I am using, in case it makes things more clear:

[Demo](https://filebin.net/z1x0oetddav3sh52)

Comment: So wait you want to add the numbers 8 44 46 86 in a list like [8,44,46,86] right? And what is the input for ```name```

Comment: what is you sample Input value for `name`??

Comment: "`numbers = names.split('\t')[1].split(' ')[1]" can you explain this, especially the last split()

Comment: To make it a little more clear, the input for the names is a string, where I have names and numbers and I remove the names, so I end up with the numbers. I could post more code, but I figured I should keep my question short, since my goal is relatively simple.

Comment: Guys if you need more code to better understand the problem, just say so. I just figured I keep my code explaination short and consise.

Comment: @PervySage sir, can u provide some sample value of your `name` variable?? because based on your post everything if looks fine.

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper The input for names is like this: 
Eline Evans\t 6338 25

All the names are structured like this. My goal is to retrieve the final two number for each of those names., and then store that number in a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all your input is structured the same way and you have the guarantee that the string ends with the 2 digits of your interest, why don't just do the following?

```
names_list = ['Andy gray\t2807 53', 'name surname\t2807 934']

for n in names_list:
  print (n[-2:])
```

On the other hand if you're not sure the last number only contains 2 digits, all the splitting on tab is unnecessary:

```
import re
names_list = ['Andy gray\t2807 53', 'name surname\t2807 94']

for n in names_list:
  try:
    if re.compile(r'.*\d+$').match(n) and ' ' in n:
      print(n.split()[-1])
  except:
    pass
```

Comment: `name surname\t2807 994` test this one

Comment: yes it's worked so I upvoted it. I don't know about OP.

Comment: It does not work. def process_names(names):
    names_list = list(names)
    for n in names_list:
        print (n.split()[-1])
and i get an error:  IndexErrorR
e
n
e
: list index out of range

Comment: This just means that not all of your strings are formatted as you expect :)
You can add a try/catch to skip the cases where there are no spaces in the string (which is the case that's getting you this error)

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper Have you tried it by using the code and input file I gave you the link to?

Comment: @hellter I have posted a link to the input file, if you're interested please have a look.

Comment: You said the format was consistent but it's not. Try with a simple try/catch, i updated the answer

Comment: The code does not work, I get letters and numbers as output, I only need to get the final number.

Comment: This is because not all your strings end with a digit. I added a regular expression to check that the extraction only is performed if this is the case. See if it works (you need to `import re`).
I also noticed that it was printing some lines with just digits. Try now.

Comment: @hellter This also does not work, and I prefer to not use imported modules. Maybe it is better if you look at link I posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

### str.rsplit()

works like str.split(), but starts from the right end.

```
s = "Andy Gray\t 2807 53"

_, number = s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
print(number)
```

Comment: I am getting the output like this now: ['Andy Pierre\t8441 71'] so this doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** after reading the code added by OP

> The code looks good, but the problem is that my input(names) is not a list of strings. I have a string like this: Guillaume van Steen 5855 5 Sven Silvis Cividjian 1539 88 Jan Willem Swarttouw 3911 66 which goes in further. This is why I split at the tab and whitespace to get the final number.

Maybe this code help:

```
from pathlib import Path

file = Path('text.txt')
text = file.read_text()
```

Here is were split the file in lines:

```
lines = text.split('\n')
```

So can use the function with a little added check

```
def get_numbers(list_of_strings):
        numbers = list()
        for string in list_of_strings:
            # here check if the line has a "\t" so asume is a valid line
            if '\t' in string:
                numbers.append(int(string.split()[-1]))
        return numbers

numbers = get_numbers(lines)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: The code looks good, but the problem is that my input(names) is not a list of strings. I have a string like this: 
Guillaume van Steen 5855 5

Sven Silvis Cividjian 1539 88

Jan Willem Swarttouw 3911 66


which goes in further. This is why I split at the tab and whitespace to get the final number.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string by whitespaces again and convert each value to int.
For example,

```
numbers = names.split('\t')[1].split(' ')[1]
list_numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers.split(' ')]
```

Then you will have your list of 'complete' digits

Comment: can you explain this??

Comment: According to the question numbers is a string "8 44 46 86 ..." and the desired result is a list of integers [8,44,46,86 ...]. This code splits the string by spaces and converts each element to integer.

Comment: This will not work since it has already been stripped of whitespace, the numbers are each printed on a separate line. I have changed the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Okay, so can you give a sample value for names @PervySage

Comment: Yes, the sample values for names are structured like this: Andy gray 2807 53

I then split by tab to get the number and then again by whitespace to get the individual numbers.